# Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists

Tags: python, generator, combinatorics

I'm trying to write some code to test out the Cartesian product of a bunch of input parameters.

I've looked at `itertools`, but its `product` function is not exactly what I want. Is there a simple obvious way to take a dictionary with an arbitrary number of keys *and* an arbitrary number of elements in each value, and then yield a dictionary with the next permutation?

Input:

```
options = {"number": [1,2,3], "color": ["orange","blue"] }
print list( my_product(options) )
```

Example output:

```
[ {"number": 1, "color": "orange"},
  {"number": 1, "color": "blue"},
  {"number": 2, "color": "orange"},
  {"number": 2, "color": "blue"},
  {"number": 3, "color": "orange"},
  {"number": 3, "color": "blue"}
]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need any library to do this, but I don't know Python quite well enough to answer. I'd guess that list comprehensions are the trick.

Comment: I'm asking if there exists a ready-made generator that can be easily adapted to do something like this. List comprehensions are not at all relevant.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Ok, thanks @dfan for telling me I was looking in the wrong place. I've got it now:

```
from itertools import product
def my_product(inp):
    return (dict(zip(inp.keys(), values)) for values in product(*inp.values())
```

**EDIT**: after years more Python experience, I think a better solution is to accept `kwargs` rather than a dictionary of inputs; the call style is more analogous to that of the original `itertools.product`. Also I think writing a generator function, rather than a function that returns a generator expression, makes the code clearer. So:

```
import itertools
def product_dict(**kwargs):
    keys = kwargs.keys()
    for instance in itertools.product(*kwargs.values()):
        yield dict(zip(keys, instance))
```

and if you need to pass in a dict, `list(product_dict(**mydict))`. The one notable change using `kwargs` rather than an arbitrary input class is that it prevents the keys/values from being ordered, at least until Python 3.6.

Comment: Does the fact that dictionary entries are stored unordered affect this in anyway?

Comment: This is a very neat code to quickly generate unit test cases (cross-validation set style!)

Comment: For Python 3 users. I have an updated version [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40623158/621449)

Comment: @Phani I would say it's okay as the keys and values, even though unordered, are still consistently ordered respectively to each others.

Comment: @Phani If you are using this list of dictionaries as a list of `**kwargs` to send to a function via `map`, then it's similar to a lot of nested for loops. The difference is that you have no guarantee of which loop is on the outside, and which loop is on the inside.

Comment: Another bonus of doing it on the guaranteed-local `kwargs` is that the user won't be able to modify (intentionally or not) the dictionary keys/values during the iteration.

Answer (score 39):

Python 3 version of [Seth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5228294/621449).

```
import itertools

def dict_product(dicts):
    """
    >>> list(dict_product(dict(number=[1,2], character='ab')))
    [{'character': 'a', 'number': 1},
     {'character': 'a', 'number': 2},
     {'character': 'b', 'number': 1},
     {'character': 'b', 'number': 2}]
    """
    return (dict(zip(dicts, x)) for x in itertools.product(*dicts.values()))
```

Comment: Might add a `.keys()` for clarity on the left side: `(dict(zip(dicts.keys(), x))`.

Answer (score 8):

By the way, this is not a permutation. A permutation is a rearrangement of a list. This is an enumeration of possible selections from lists.

Edit: after remembering that it was called a Cartesian product, I came up with this:

```
import itertools
options = {"number": [1,2,3], "color": ["orange","blue"] }
product = [x for x in apply(itertools.product, options.values())]
print([dict(zip(options.keys(), p)) for p in product])
```

Comment: I was trying to explain why looking up "permutations" wasn't helping. I remembered what this actually is: it's a Cartesian product. I would start by looking at itertools.product().

Comment: Yep, done, and thanks for the pointer. But still, welcome to Stack Overflow: an answer should be one that actually provides an answer the question. This belongs as a comment on the question.

Comment: @user470379 not really, the original version didn't state Cartesian product

Comment: I don't seem to have the ability to comment on anything but my own answers yet. I would have put it there if I could. I'm glad my answer led you to the solution.

Comment: Ah, understood. Well, thanks again for your help in setting me on the right track.

Comment: In Python 3, you have to replace `apply(itertools.product, options.values())` with `itertools.product(*options.values())`

Answer (score 4):

```
# I would like to do
keys,values = options.keys(), options.values()
# but I am not sure that the keys and values would always
# be returned in the same relative order. Comments?
keys = []
values = []
for k,v in options.iteritems():
    keys.append(k)
    values.append(v)

import itertools
opts = [dict(zip(keys,items)) for items in itertools.product(*values)]
```

results in

```
opts = [
    {'color': 'orange', 'number': 1},
    {'color': 'orange', 'number': 2},
    {'color': 'orange', 'number': 3},
    {'color': 'blue', 'number': 1},
    {'color': 'blue', 'number': 2},
    {'color': 'blue', 'number': 3}
]
```

Comment: I think Python guarantees that keys() and values() and their corresponding iter* will return in the same order. See http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items

Comment: @Seth: Excellent! Thank you, that had been bothering me for a while.

Comment: you're quite welcome. It's very handy, and especially for this case. If you review my answer, you can see that the iterkeys/itervalues methods will save you from creating a bunch of temporaries, too.