# nesting to a dynamic depth in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, nested

I have a problem I'm trying to solve which requires nesting as many levels deep as there are items in a list.  Or to be precise, iterables in a list.

```
def example(arg_list):
for i in arg_list[0]:
    for j in arg_list[1]:
        for k in arg_list[2]:
            print "{} {} {}".format(i,j,k)
```

The above function would run fine as long as the "arg_list" is a list containing 3 iterables, such as [[1,3,4],[4,5,6], [9,3,2,1,0]].  If there were always four iterables in the list, that would be easy to do as well.  I need to figure out how to create a function that will add another nested level for each iterable added to the "arg_list" parameter.  It seems that recursion might be the way to go, but haven't been able to figure that out.

Comment: can you give an example of the output you want?

Comment: Is it possible for a list to contain mixed types? For example,  `[1,2,[1,2,3]]` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228158/cartesian-product-of-a-dictionary-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use recursion, something like:

```
def example(arg_list, res=[]):
    if arg_list == []:
        print res
        return
    for i in arg_list[0]:
        example(arg_list[1:], res+[i])
```

Answer (score 8):

What you are looking for is called a *Cartesian product.* Python's `itertools` module has a function that will do that for you.

```
from itertools import product

def example(arg_list):
    for items in product(*arg_list):
        print " ".join(str(item) for item in items)
```

Comment: this works, i should have checked itertools.   Small edit, since product was imported by itself, it should read "for items in product(*arg_list):... no need to say "...in itertools.product..."