# C# get IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> from Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> by cartesian product

Tags: c#, cartesian-product

from this dictionary

```
var foo = new Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>>
        {
            {"key1", new object[] {1}}, 
            {"key2", new[] {"one", "two"}}, 
            {"key3", new[] {"three", "four"}}
        }
```

i'd like to get this IEnumerable<dictionary<string, object>>

```
IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> bar = {
     {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", "one"}, {"key3", "three"}},
     {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", "one"}, {"key3", "four"}},
     {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", "two"}, {"key3", "three"}},
     {{"key1", 1}, {"key2", "two"}, {"key3", "four"}}
}
```

To speak simply, I need C#'s analog of python itertools.product function [Cartesian product of a dictionary of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228158/cartesian-product-of-a-dictionary-of-lists).

I've read [Generating all Possible Combinations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093622/generating-all-possible-combinations) but couldn't figure out how i should change it and i couldn't found solution about cartesian product with dictionaries (with keys) result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried following
public static IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> CartesianProductT(            Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<object>> sequences)
        {
            IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>> emptyProduct = new[] {new Dictionary<string, object>()};
            return sequences.Aggregate(emptyProduct, (accumulator, sequence) => accumulator.SelectMany(_ => sequence.Value, (acc, item) =>{
                    acc.TryAdd(sequence.Key, item);
                    return acc;
                }));
        }
but it returns 4 duplicates of first row of needed result

Comment: @vvkirik1, please note that the return type cannot be `IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>`, maybe it should be  `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick solution would be to do only cartesian product of dictionary values while preserving information about keys, and next recreate dictionaries:

```
           // [[("key1",1)],[("key2","one"),("key2,"two")],[("key3","three"),("key3","four")]]
            var collectionsOfKeyValuePairs =
                foo.Select(k => k.Value.Select(v => new KeyValuePair<string, object>(k.Key, v)));
            // [[(key1,1),(key2,one),(key3,three)],
            //  [(key1,1),(key2,one),(key3,four)],...etc
            var product = CartesianProduct(collectionsOfKeyValuePairs);
            
            var dictionaries = product.Select(collection=> collection.ToDictionary(k=> k.Key, k=> k.Value));
```